# How to make icicle-pp-eval-expression use eldoc like eval-expression?

Tags: eval-expression, icicles

In recent Emacs versions, `eval-expression` makes use of `global-eldoc-mode` in a quite intelligent way, using the modeline to display hints.  However, `icicle-pp-eval-expression`, which is Icicles' variant of `eval-expression`, does not have this functionality.  How to enable it?  Simple grepping for `eldoc` in the body of `eval-expression` didn't show any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I will take a look to see what, if anything, I think might be done as an improvement.
2. `C-h f icicle-pp-eval-expression` tells you how to do without that function:

   ```
   By default, Icicle mode remaps all key sequences that are normally
   bound to `eval-expression` or `pp-eval-expression` to
   `icicle-pp-eval-expression`.  If you do not want this remapping, then
   customize option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`.
   ```

   That should at least give you a workaround.

---

**UPDATE**

Should be OK now. Please download the latest [**`icicles-cmd1.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el) from Emacs Wiki (or wait up to a day for it to be mirrored on MELPA).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, something went wrong with the upgrade process, and I'm left without Icicles. Ouch. I guess I'll just install them from EW manually.

Comment: OK, so I downloaded Icicles manually from EW, and I can confirm that your change works as expected. Thanks a lot!